# How to send a JSON FILE in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm trying to build a Web Api with .NET 6 / CORE 3.1,
that sends the content of a json file located in the directory of the code when
an user hit the route "/getJSON". I don't if I've to serialize JSON before send it,
how to send it correctly and many other doubts.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

    public class SuperHeroController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpGet("/getJSON")]
        public ActionResult GetJson()
        {
            string jsonFile = JsonSerializer.Serialize("myjson.json");

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");

            return Ok(jsonFile);
        }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what You're looking for:)

If this myjson.json file is a correct json file try this:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("myjson.json");
var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
```

(return jsonObject)

or return it as File (more here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fileresult-in-asp-net-core-mvc2/ )